# Subscripting a list in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, list

I have a list of items, and I'd like to access the first item like below, but get an error when I compile:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!items[0]}" />
Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Number
```

So I thought I'd try passing in a string like it says it wants. This compiled fine but gave another error at runtime:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!items['0']}" />
Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text
```

After this, I tried one last approach just out of curiosity:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!items[items.size-items.size]}" />
```

This final version compiles and works correctly at runtime, but I'm reluctant to rely on such an unusual syntax... Does anybody know why this is happening? Is there a correct way to subscript a list in VisualForce?

Comment: It may also be worth noting that `{!items[items.size-1]}` works fine to get the last item in the list, but `{!items[0]}` still throws an error at compile time

Comment: Square brackets were introduced for [Dynamic Visualforce Bindings](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf.htm) and also work on string keyed maps. Interesting that your last example works; I think I'd feel safer adding a controller property called `itemZero` even though that is inelegant...

Comment: Thanks for that link! According to the documentation then, it's definitely not supposed to work like this. The usage `{!items[items.size-1]}` must just be undefined behavior. I'll definitely use an alternative here (an `itemZero` getter seems like a good idea, and won't require adding a new variable to the controller) to avoid any issues in relying on this syntax

Comment: The expression language in Visualforce seems under-documented to me so yeah its hard to know what is "by design" and so guaranteed to keep working versus what is "by accident".

Comment: I haven't tried it, but could an [`<apex:variable>`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_variable.htm) help you out here? Set the variable value to the number `0` and then use the variable as the index.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, I tried that but still got the first error `Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Number`. Somehow it seems like it can detect that this the variable is a number, but not `items.size-items.size`

Comment: Apexonauts  unite and vote for having officially `index` support:https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GmlCAAS&sort=2